# how to locate the file in ftp using php

Tags: php, upload, ftp

I try to upload a file in C:\data\image.jpg to my ftp server (000webhost)

I use the code as follows

```
   <?php
    // FTP access parameters
    $host = 'nana.host56.com';
    $usr = 'a4491289';
    $pwd = '+++';

    // file to move:
    $local_file = 'C:\data\image.jpg';
    $ftp_path = '/public_html/';

    // connect to FTP server (port 21)
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");


    // send access parameters
    ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");

    // turn on passive mode transfers (some servers need this)
    // ftp_pasv ($conn_id, true);

    // perform file upload
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);

    // check upload status:
    print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
    print "\n";

    /*
    ** Chmod the file (just as example)
    */

    // If you are using PHP4 then you need to use this code:
    // (because the "ftp_chmod" command is just available in PHP5+)
    if (!function_exists('ftp_chmod')) {
       function ftp_chmod($ftp_stream, $mode, $filename){
            return ftp_site($ftp_stream, sprintf('CHMOD %o %s', $mode, $filename));
       }
    }

    // try to chmod the new file to 666 (writeable)
    if (ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0666, $ftp_path) !== false) {
        print $ftp_path . " chmoded successfully to 666\n";
    } else {
        print "could not chmod $file\n";
    }


// close the FTP stream
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

and it display **Warning:** ftp_put(C:\data\image.jpg) [function.ftp-put]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  /home/a4491289/public_html/upload.php

Is there something wrong with the file path and the local file? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try using ftp_chdir to the $ftp_dir before uploading the file and in the remote path use the file name you want to upload. ie:

```
ftp_chrdir('/public_html/');
ftp_put($con, 'ftp_image.jpg', 'real_image.jpg', FTP_ASCII);
```

Or you can try to supply the full path of the destination file and not just '/public_html/'.

Take a look at the example at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think the file path is wrong but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Is there any help? I spent hours to find the solution but it is impossible. Thanks

Comment: You can check the path of the public_html folder by printing the current directory via php script. Just create a PHP script there and echo getcwd(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: Thank you. I think the path to the local file is wrong. How to fix it? I tried several times but it  does not work

Comment: upload a php file to the directory you want to save the images with the code "echo dirname(__FILE__);" and run it with the browser and it should print out the full path to the directory.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. I think the file path on my laptop is wrong, not on server. Now I want to correct the file path C:\data\image.jpg so that the image can be found by php code

Comment: just put the image in the same directory as the script that uploads it and then you will only need to supply the file name without the full path.

Comment: The php file stays on server and my image is on my laptop. I want to upload the image to the server by using the php script. I found that many people face the same problem but no one has the right answer. Thank you.

Comment: Oh I see now, you want to upload a file on your computer through the PHP script, the thing is that the PHP script uses the file system of the server (server side scripting) so you need to add a form with an input type file and submit that form to upload a file to the server from the computer: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php check this tutorial, should give you the idea on how to do so... If you want it to be automatically then you will need to setup a php server on your computer and run the script locally to upload the image to the server from the computer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know how to use the input type file and HTML form. However, what I really want is to upload a file on my laptop to remote web server (000webhost) without using input type file. That's why I try to use ftp via php. I found some code on the Internet as in my post but I dont know why the php script cannot find the local file on my laptop.

Comment: Because the PHP script runs on the server and not on your computer and accesses the server's file system. So in your case it's trying to find a dir with the name c: and then go to it and the rest of the path in the same directory that the script is in. You will need to run the script from the computer that the file you are trying to upload is located on. Or you can always write a batch script that will use the ftp command to do so. Server side scripts can't access to the client side file system without something like input type file.